# Form data not available in python script

Tags: python, cgi

Consider the following script `test.py` on an Apache server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi

cgi.test()
```

If I call `http://domain.local/test.py?foo=bar` the output says (among others):

```
QUERY_STRING
REQUEST_METHOD
    GET

Command Line Arguments
[]

Form Contents:
No form fields.
```

If I send the data by using a POST request, the `QUERY_STRING` and `REQUEST_METHOD` do not show up at all, not to say that form contents section is still empty.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with a workaround:

```
import urlparse
import sys

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

data=dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(sys.stdin.read()))

for field in data:
   print field,data[field]
```

In my specific case, the script will only accept POST data (I would have use $_POST in PHP, discarding $_GET). It could easily be modified in order to be able to parse GET data, be it instead of or in addition to POST.

I would, however, still be interested in knowing why the initial approach did not work out.